# Exception from JsonRpc server and semantic analyzer bot working in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio

```
StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: SyntaxTree is not part of the compilation (Parameter 'syntaxTree')
```

at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.d__151`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.BrokeredServiceConnection`1.<TryInvokeAsync>d__20`1.MoveNext()
RPC server exception:
System.ArgumentException: SyntaxTree is not part of the compilation (Parameter 'syntaxTree')
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.GetSemanticModel(SyntaxTree syntaxTree, Boolean ignoreAccessibility)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document.GetSemanticModelAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Shared.Extensions.DocumentExtensions.GetRequiredSemanticModelAsync(Document document, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Classification.AbstractEmbeddedLanguageClassificationService.AddEmbeddedLanguageClassificationsAsync(Document document, TextSpan textSpan, ClassificationOptions options, SegmentedList`1 result, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Classification.AbstractClassificationService.AddClassificationsInCurrentProcessAsync(Document document, TextSpan textSpan, ClassificationType type, ClassificationOptions options, SegmentedList`1 result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.RemoteSemanticClassificationService.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.RemoteWorkspace.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<<RunWithSolutionAsync>g__ProcessSolutionAsync|1>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.RemoteWorkspace.RunWithSolutionAsync[T](AssetProvider assetProvider, Checksum solutionChecksum, Int32 workspaceVersion, Boolean updatePrimaryBranch, Func`2 implementation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.RemoteWorkspace.RunWithSolutionAsync[T](AssetProvider assetProvider, Checksum solutionChecksum, Int32 workspaceVersion, Boolean updatePrimaryBranch, Func`2 implementation, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.BrokeredServiceBase.RunWithSolutionAsync[T](Checksum solutionChecksum, Func`2 implementation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.BrokeredServiceBase.RunServiceImplAsync[T](Func`2 implementation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)